# Как получить position EditText в формате строки используя BaseAdapter?

Tags: java, android

Суть такова. У меня есть `ListView`

```
private ListView list;

private String[] names = {"Русский язык", "Математика", "Обществознание", "Биология", "Иностранный язык", "История", "Химия", "География", "Информатика", "Литература", "Физика"};
private int[] images = {R.drawable.icons1, R.drawable.icons2, R.drawable.icons3, R.drawable.icons4, R.drawable.icons5, R.drawable.icons6, R.drawable.icons7, R.drawable.icons8, R.drawable.icons9, R.drawable.icons9, R.drawable.icons10, R.drawable.icons11};

ArrayList<ResorsesForRow> resorsesForRows = new ArrayList<ResorsesForRow>();

private Button button;
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bals2);

    button = findViewById(R.id.button);

    list = findViewById(R.id.listView);

    for(int i=0; i<11; i++){
        resorsesForRows.add(new ResorsesForRow(names[i], images[i]));
        Log.d(TAG, names[i]);
    }

    AdapterForList adapterForList = new AdapterForList(this, resorsesForRows);
    list.setAdapter(adapterForList);

}
```

Есть адаптер наследованный от `BaseAdapter`

```
public class AdapterForList extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    ArrayList<ResorsesForRow> rows;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    AdapterForList(Context ctx, ArrayList<ResorsesForRow> list){
        context = ctx;
        rows = list;
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return rows.size();     // Общее кол-во элиментов
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return rows.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;

        if(view==null){
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_for_listview, parent, false);
        }

        ResorsesForRow resorsesForRow = getResorsessForRow(position);

        ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        imageView.setImageResource(resorsesForRow.img);
        TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        textView.setText(resorsesForRow.name);
        EditText editText = view.findViewById(R.id.edittext);

        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                int ball = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());
                if(ball<=100){
                    sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("pref", MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sharedPreferences.edit();
                    Object position;
                    edit.putString(position.toString(), text inside edittext);
                    edit.apply();
                }
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    ResorsesForRow getResorsessForRow(int position) {
        return (ResorsesForRow) getItem(position);
    }
}
```

Мне нужно как-то получить внутри метода `afterTextChanged()` позицию (порядковый номер) `EditText` и затем передать его в качестве ключа в `SharedPreferences`, а в качестве значения использовать введенное число. Я не понимаю как я могу получить номер позиции `EditText`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю вам это поможет. Здесь уже есть реализованый onTextChanged в адаптере.

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private String[] mDataset;

public MyAdapter(String[] myDataset) {
    mDataset = myDataset;
}

@Override
public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                               int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_edittext, parent, false);
    // pass MyCustomEditTextListener to viewholder in onCreateViewHolder
    // so that we don't have to do this expensive allocation in onBindViewHolder
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v, new MyCustomEditTextListener());

    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    // update MyCustomEditTextListener every time we bind a new item
    // so that it knows what item in mDataset to update
    holder.myCustomEditTextListener.updatePosition(holder.getAdapterPosition());
    holder.mEditText.setText(mDataset[holder.getAdapterPosition()]);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataset.length;
}


public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    // each data item is just a string in this case
    public EditText mEditText;
    public MyCustomEditTextListener myCustomEditTextListener;

    public ViewHolder(View v, MyCustomEditTextListener myCustomEditTextListener) {
        super(v);

        this.mEditText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        this.myCustomEditTextListener = myCustomEditTextListener;
        this.mEditText.addTextChangedListener(myCustomEditTextListener);
    }
}

// we make TextWatcher to be aware of the position it currently works with
// this way, once a new item is attached in onBindViewHolder, it will
// update current position MyCustomEditTextListener, reference to which is kept by ViewHolder
private class MyCustomEditTextListener implements TextWatcher {
    private int position;

    public void updatePosition(int position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
        // no op
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
        mDataset[position] = charSequence.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        // no op
    }
}
}
```

Comment: В вопросе `ListView`, а не `RV`

Answer (score 1):

1. Вот же номер позиции: `int position`.
2. Вынеси работу с `SharedPreferences` из адаптера. Адаптер должен делать только одну вещь, а именно рисовать элементы списка.
3. Используй `Recyclerview` или реализуй паттерн `Viewholder`, т.к. в данной реализации, при каждом вызове метода getView вызываются методы `findViewById`(а это очень ресурсоемкая операция). На больших списках твой адаптер будет лагать.